# Cakephp Translate Behavior

Tags: php, refactoring, cakephp-2.0

Here is how we use Translate behavior with cakephp model relationship. I'm trying hard to raise quality of this piece of code.

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Faq->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid faq'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Faq->saveMany($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The faq has been saved', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The faq could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Faq.' . $this->Faq->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Faq->find('first', $options);
    }
    $languages = $this->Language->getlangs();
    if(is_array($this->{$this->modelClass}->belongsTo)) {
        foreach($this->{$this->modelClass}->belongsTo as $relation => $model) {
            foreach($languages as $lang){
                    $this->{$this->modelClass}->$model['className']->locale = $lang['Language']['language_locale'];
                $faqCategories[$lang['Language']['language_locale']] = $this->Faq->FaqCategory->find('list', array('conditions' => array('FaqCategory.is_active' => 1), 'recursive' => 1));
            }
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('faqCategories'));
}
```

It works fine, but I would like to have a quality code with equal functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TranslateBehavior is actually quite easy to setup and works out of the box with very little configuration. In this section, you will learn how to add and setup the behavior to use in any model.

If you are using TranslateBehavior in alongside containable issue, be sure to set the ‘fields’ key for your queries. Otherwise you could end up with invalid SQL generated.

****Initializing the i18n Database Tables****

```
./cake i18n
```

For correct layout.

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Translate'
    );
}
```

Reading translated content

By default the **TranslateBehavior** will automatically fetch and add in data based on the current locale. The current locale is read from Configure::read('Config.language') which is assigned by the L10n class. You can override this default on the fly using

```
$Model->locale
```